# How Do I Link My Local Bash Shell To Files In Azure?

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I've been doing some work using Azure Cloud Shell but now I want to use my native terminal instead of the browser shell.

I have [installed the azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest) and I can login using `az login`.

How do I locally work on the files that were previously accessible from the command line in the cloud shell?

```
find . -not -path '*/\.*'
.
./clouddrive
./terraform
./terraform/variables.tf
./terraform/terraform.tfstate
./terraform/terraform.tfstate.backup
./terraform/main.tf
```

E.g. is it possible to mount that terraform directory? Or is is there some other way of working with the files I created in cloud shell?

Comment: You cannot just connect with your Web App file system via local `az`. That's what the cloud shell is for. If you need to work with your files locally, just edit them locally, and make them part of your deployment.

Comment: Any more questions? Or if the answer helps you solve the problem you can mark it.

Comment: Mounting the Azure File Share isn't as straight forward as it seems https://superuser.com/questions/1409333/is-my-router-blocking-smb-445

Comment: I have added the answer to the question, it works well and the files in the file share shown in the mount point.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Cloud Shell, it's also a Linux system associated with the Azure File Share and the OS file is stored in the File Share. So you can mount the File Share to your VM and then you can use the file in it.

But you should move the directory to the path:

```
/home/charles/clouddrive
```

The screenshot of the test like this:

[image]
[image]

Then you can mount the File Share to your VM following the steps in [Mount Azure File Share to Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).